# Persist only entity attributes belonging to a certain group

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

In my Symfony 5.2 controller, I am partially deserializing an entity, using the `@Groups` annotation.

```php
$serializer->deserialize(
    $request->getContent(),
    MyEntity::class,
    'json',
    [AbstractNormalizer::OBJECT_TO_POPULATE => $myEntity, AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['updatable']]);
```

This is used to update an entity that already exists.

Now Symfony only deserializes the fields marked with the `updatable` group as intended, and I want to persist and save only the fields with the `updatable` group.

Unfortunately, the clean way to persist entities does not allow persisting based on groups.

```php
$em->persist($myentity); // Persists all fields
```

This obviously leads to errors when flushing, since the non `updatable` fields are set to null or default values, which I do not want to persist.

Is there any simple built-in way to persist specific columns only based on groups?

Comment: Your instance of `$serializer` is injected or you have create the instance ? And have you adding `$normalizer` and `$encoder` ?

Comment: It's the injected one, but it works great. I only included the snippet for context. The question I have is about updating some fields of an existing entity using the entity manager.